# iOS Detect unwind segue from push segue

Tags: ios, segue, pushviewcontroller, unwind-segue

I need to detect an unwind segue from a child to a parent view controller. I know it is possible to do this if I have a button that initiates to unwind segue, but is there a way to detect it if I just use the standard back button that is created automatically

```
@IBAction func unwind(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {

    println("segue did unwind")

}
```

I have tried by putting this into the parent view controller, and then connected (ctrl+drag) from the child view controller to exit. But this doesn't call the above method

Comment: The standard back button doesn't do an unwind segue. It does popViewControllerAnimated:. Why do you want to do an unwind?

Comment: @rdelmar ah, then i've got confused. So is there a way of detecting when the back button is pressed (or screen swiped back), so that I can pass information back to the parent view controller?

Comment: Normally, you wouldn't wait until the user pushes the back button to pass the information. Pass it using a delegate protocol as soon as the information is available to pass, then you don't need to detect when the back button is touched.

Answer (score 0):

When You want to transition to the parent screen using the `Back` button, do to control-drag from the button to the parent VC. Control-Drag from the button to the `Exit` present on the top of VC. then select your unwind segue from the list.

Hope this helps. :)